# Make pdfjs work on local files

Tags: internet-explorer, local-storage, pdf.js

I am tasked with using PDFjs in a local environment. Everything works fine to the point that I can use absolute paths for the PDFs to circumvent the same origin policy, and in firefox, viewing a local PDF like this

```
<iframe class="pdf-viewer" src="viewer.html?file=file:///c/work/example-files/pdf/test.pdf"></iframe>
```

Works just fine. The problem is, that as soon as I try the same in Internet Explorer, I get the error that `getItem` of an undefined or null reference cannot be called.

This boils down to the fact that when using local file system, in Internet Explorer the `localStorage` is `undefined`.

Is there a way to make *PDFjs* **not** use the local storage, so this works in IE, too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, IE has limited support and if you're using a version that is not HTML5 compliant, you'll need to include compatibility.js which has polyfills for missing features

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#faq-support

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/wiki/Required-Browser-Features

If you really want to get deeper and handle this scenario, you can try modifying the PDF.js code itself

https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Answer (score 2):

pdf.js makes very clever use of HTTP `GET` requests with `range` headers to only download portions of the file (random file access), which once the file has been loaded once, are satisfied fully from the **browser cache** You can observe this effect by looking at the network monitor tab, what looks like multiple requests for the same file are really multiple requests with different byte ranges. So to load page 123 of a 450 page document, it only has to look at a specific byte range and not keep the whole file in browser memory.

Apparently with file://, there is no browser cache, so it has to put the file data somewhere, for huge PDF files, it simply cannot keep it all in memory. Thus the requirement for `localstorage`.
If you knew for certain that all of your PDF files would fit in memory, you could write a `localstorage` polyfill that keeps the PDF data in memory rather than in true `localstorage`. You will be pretty memory constrained on a 32 bit browser though.